# Should the server treat unsanitized requests as invalid?

Tags: validation

Should the server respond with a 405 or similar when given unsanitized data? Similar to how a request is invalidated when the user is not authorized to perform the requested action.

Answer (score 0):

its simply due to permission on resources that you are going to use , is not gained by program for that role .